# jQuerySmoothScroll Plugin for WordPress Header above content

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, header, smooth-scrolling

I installed the jQuery Smooth Scroll Plugin for my OnePage WordPress Site. It works really fine at scrolling smooth to the top, but it gets the Position wrong (overlay the anchorcontent (exactly headerheight overlay)) when scrolling down to an anchor via menuclick. When Header "toggled" on top, there is a little way of scrolling down where it disappears and suddenly some more pixels down it is fixed at the top of the Browser-Window. I think this abruptly disappear/appear action cause this problem, but that doesn't have to mean anything as I am not good at coding etc.

This is the Plugin Code. Header height is 80px.

```javascript
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($) {


// Customize Settings: For more information visit                                   www.blogsynthesis.com/plugins/jquery-smooth-scroll/

// When to show the scroll link
// higher number = scroll link appears further down the page    
var upperLimit = 100; 

// Our scroll link element
var scrollElem = $('a#scroll-to-top');

// Scroll Speed. Change the number to change the speed
var scrollSpeed = 600;

// Choose your easing effect http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html
var scrollStyle = 'swing';

/****************************************************
*                                                  *
   *      JUMP TO ANCHOR LINK SCRIPT START            *
 *                                                  *
 ****************************************************/

// Show and hide the scroll to top link based on scroll position    
scrollElem.hide();
$(window).scroll(function () {          
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();        
    if ( scrollTop > upperLimit ) {
        $(scrollElem).stop().fadeTo(300, 1); // fade back in            
    }else{      
        $(scrollElem).stop().fadeTo(300, 0); // fade out
    }
});

// Scroll to top animation on click
$(scrollElem).click(function(){ 
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, scrollSpeed, scrollStyle ); return false; 
});

      /****************************************************
  *                                                  *
  *      JUMP TO ANCHOR LINK SCRIPT START            *
  *                                                  *
  ****************************************************/

  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]):not([href^="#tab"])').click(function() 
{
     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) 
{

  var target = $(this.hash),
  headerHeight = $(".primary-header").height() + 5; // Get fixed header height

  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

  if (target.length) 
  {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, scrollSpeed, scrollStyle );
    return false;
  }
}
 });


 /****************************************************
 *                                                  *
  *   FOLLOW BLOGSYNTHESIS.COM FOR WORDPRESS TIPS    *
*                                                  *
****************************************************/

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean, but I think your saying that the anchor gets covered up by the header when you scroll to the element.

If that is the case, you could add this `CSS` to fix that:

```
:target:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:80px; /* fixed header height*/
    margin:-80px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```

I'm not really sure what you mean by the rest of your post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Advice. I copied your Code to the style.css and compressed in the style.min.css but nothing changed. I try to describe the Situation more exactly: The header is like the one in this demo [link](https://kingthe.me/vixa/demo-ancy/) and with the JSS Plugin and the code above in my first Comment, i think there is the problem, that the Header is not be calculated into the offset when going down from the top of the page(because it shortly disappears) but when going up or between each anchors it works when i set Headerheight to fix -85 and targetoffset -85..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Try this one without a plugin

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I pasted your Code in a file "smooth.js" and put it in wp-includes/js/. Than i tried to load it via `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_js_include_function' );


function my_js_include_function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'smooth.js', '/js/smooth.js', array('jquery') );
}` But nothing happened.